# When is perturbation used for data privacy/security?

Tags: data-security

I know that data perturbation is now preferred in data privacy/security since it hurts truthfulness, but it is also used in some areas. Does anybody know where it is used? I couldn't find a research or article about it.
Below link is a good resource to get some background information. Link:[https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220373844_Protecting_Data_through_Perturbation_Techniques_The_Impact_on_Knowledge_Discovery_in_Databases#:~:text=Abstract,lead%20to%20a%20security%20breach](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220373844_Protecting_Data_through_Perturbation_Techniques_The_Impact_on_Knowledge_Discovery_in_Databases#:%7E:text=Abstract,lead%20to%20a%20security%20breach).